# button width flowing outside of div to the end of the page

Tags: html, css, width

So, when I hover on a div, I can make an h3 and P change color, and I am trying to display a button inside that same div. however when I hover on the div, the button's width flows outside of the div's right side, all the way to the end of the page.

```
HTML
<div class="box-container">
   <div class="odd box">
     <h3 class="box-h">BOX NUMBER 1</h3>
     <p class="box-p">USELESS SUBTEXT</p>
     <button class="box-b">VIEW THE CASE STUDY</button>
   </div>
 (there are 5 more "odd box" divs inside of "box-container", just thought I would spare you seeing 5 more replica "odd box" divs)
...
```

```
SCSS
.box-b {
  display: none;
}

.box:hover .box-b {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: $btn-gray;
  color: $white;
  height: 60px;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwwVf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to the parent div. That will keep the button from flowing outside of the parent div.

```
.box {
  position: relative;
}
```